# how to export jar file contains .class with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to add some Unicode character to JAR file, therefore I decompile the JAR file with JAVA DECOMPILER and after that I was be able to add Unicode character with Eclipse. So I need to create JAR file again after modification. I export JAR file from project and everything seems ok. But I have some problem. When I opened the original file with Java decompiler (before modification) everything is .class, after modification and export JAR with eclipse everything is .java, how can I export JAR file with eclipse as original file with .class instead .java?

before decompile and modification 
[image]

after decompile and modification with eclipse
[image]

both file is jar before and after modification.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this way 
File menu --> Export --> select JAR file --> select the resources folder --> finish

for reference [enter link description here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm)

Comment: when I done with this way the JAR file contains java file not class file. as I attached pictures on the above post.